# How to query the DB to find an element inside a column that contain a json data from a multi select (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

This is what I've in my "attrib" db column data:

```
["last","featured","disabled"]
```

I try to add in my query something like

```
->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?,attrib)', ['featured'])
```

but it not works...

**UPDATE**
I've resolved with:

```
$featured = Course::where('attrib', 'like', '%featured%')->get();
```

But I'm still looking for a better query without the use of "LIKE".

Answer (score 0):

You may use whereIn() in your model

```
$attrib=["last","featured","disabled"];
->whereIn('attrib',[$attrib])->get();
```

Comment: This solution not work for me.
$featured = Course::whereIn('attrib',['featured'])->get();
empty result+